How to manage sending transactions for a wallet used for a server?
When the users wants to withdraw their funds from the contract (on Arbitrun), the backend of my app does that for them to verify from the database that they can.
I recently got "Nonce too low" error, and that got me thinking. When users use the same backend wallet to send transactions at the same time, will this cause problems?
ChatGPT suggested i setup a transaction queue to synchronize nonce management.
Is there any other way to avoid transactions from colliding?
const transactionQueue = [];

async function processQueue() {
    while (transactionQueue.length > 0) {
        const { txParams, resolve, reject } = transactionQueue.shift();
        try {
            const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(yourAddress, "latest");
            const tx = await wallet.sendTransaction({ ...txParams, nonce });
            await tx.wait();
            resolve(tx);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    }
}

function queueTransaction(txParams) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        transactionQueue.push({ txParams, resolve, reject });
        if (transactionQueue.length === 1) {
            processQueue();
        }
    });
}


The simplest way, would be to queue transactions using getTransactionCount. For every transaction you send:

Check the current nonce of the wallet using getTransactionCount
Check if you have any pending transactions with the same nonce.
Add your nonce accordingly.

What probably happened in your specific example was that you checked the transaction count before a transaction had finished and assigned the same nonce.
A pretty common trick is to use some kind of database for transactions and nonces, and a function to "force" the nonce to be reset (like, for example if a number of transactions fail, and the internal nonce counter is now all messed up).
There are other tricks like potentially making all transactions "blocking" actions, and synchronous. But the simplest is to just use getTransactionCount (or, whatever API you'd like to use to get nonce) and assign it accordingly.
For more context, a great codebase to look at is the Chainlink node software which has to process potentially thousands of transactions a minute and has fantastic nonce management (written in go).

This is essentially a concurrency problem in distributed systems, which is that: at any time, only one process can handle the correct nonce. The solution is to ensure that when all processes use nonce, they will not conflict with other servers, and after use, other servers can synchronize to the latest nonce:

Distributed lock: such as redis
Database lock: such as optimistic lock or pessimistic lock
Other components that can be shared and stored by the server, even smart contracts

